# How do I scale my text size for multi-device compatibility on Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am having trouble scaling my text size based on the user's device. I use constraint layout to constrain the TextViews. I found that autoTextSize could be used to automatically fit my text in the TextViews. However, when I run my code on an Emulator like BlueStacks, some texts are not scaled properly. Weirdly, some work but some do not, even though I am implementing it the same way.

This is an example of what it looks like: The register button is in a big font but other texts aren't [image]
This is what it looks like on my layout Editor: [image]

My code for the register button:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="5:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.541" />
```

my code for the "up to 8 characters" text.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/req"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:text="*up to 8 characters"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="7:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.538" />
```

Am I misusing autoSizeTextType somehow?

Also, my "Enter Username" text is very small. I use EditText and implement it the same way I did for the other two texts. If there is anyway I can make the font size bigger to fit the layout size, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `<TextView android:id="@+id/register"` is using `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` attr, `<TextView android:id="@+id/req"` have `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` - note the difference `app`/`android`. try to consolidate this param, you should probably use `app` in both/all `TextView`s

note that [`setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(int)) was introduced in API 26, so when you use `android:` prefix then this attr will be respected only on 26+. using custom `app:` makes this attr usable for `TextView` (in fact `TextViewCompat`) on any OS version

in Android Studio above layout preview you have an option to switch "Device to preview" and also API version - try to change to some older (in this sample 25 at most, preferably lowest supported `minSdkVersion`) or newest OS version, IDE should catch and show differences in look

Answer (score 1):

Use TextView params like this

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
```

You can check the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) for more info.